# Adding a Groovy web console into eclipse(j2ee) and run it at apache tomcat

Tags: eclipse, compiler-construction, groovy, interpreter

Is there anyone that has done a java interpreter using groovy-all jar file? Maybe sample or example can share it to me or teach me? I meant a interpreter that can parse string(java code) into the textarea and output it as a result like(hello world)

Answer (score 0):

As you need some sample code to implement a web-console using `groovy-all.jar`, it would strongly recommend taking a look at [Groovy Web Console](https://github.com/glaforge/groovywebconsole).

Although it's not exactly a Java EE / Tomcat app and it is fairly similar as its a standard Java Servlets API 2.5 based web app. It runs on Google App Engine, which you can try out [here](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com). All you need from it is the script execution logic which for most of the part is not app engine specific. Keep in mind, it has dependencies on GAE Apis (through [Gaelyk](http://gaelyk.appspot.com)) so you should prune that part out of it to run in it outside Google App Engine.

Comment: that i cant implement it in eclipse as that is a error"impossible to parse JSON response:syntaxError: unexpected token < " when i press on the execute button. 
you have any idea how to solve it?

Comment: without the context, not really sure where and would this come.